# Heatmap from geojson points in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, heatmap

I am attempting to create a simple heatmap from a feature collection of points using leaflet's heatmap plugin.  After successfully getting the json data from an ajax call, I create an empty coords array and push coordinates from each feature.

However, this method does not work and neither does the [geojson2heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/issues/64) function.  There are no errors in the console.   What am I doing wrong and does anyone know of a workaround?

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([50.0647, 19.9450], 12);

var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("newmap.geojson");

coords = [];

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            coords.push(feature.geometry.coordinates);

};

L.GeoJSON(geojsonLayer, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
})

var heat = L.heatLayer(coords).addTo(map);
```

The structure of the geojson is standard:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "st_x": 19.952030181884801, "st_y": 50.055513141929701 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 19.952030181884801, 50.055513141929701 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "st_x": 18.672015, "st_y": 50.287181666666697 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 18.672015, 50.287181666666697 ] } },
```

Answer (score 2):

I am mostly doing the same as you but with Mapbox, which is based on Leaflet.

The problem I had is that the latitude and longitude coordinates of the GeoJSON were reversed. There were no errors on console either- points were just not showing on map. So, you need:

```
"coordinates": [ longitude, latitude ]
```

Hope that's the issue.